# ng-bootstrap with .net core 2 angular 4 template not working

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, ng-bootstrap

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for several days now and think I'm super close but must be missing something really simple / critical.
I've created a new site using "dotnet new angular" using the latest install of dot net 2.0 and the associated templates.  I then upgraded the bootstrap package to 4.0 beta and removed the JavaScript components and jQuery.  All of that is working great.
Now I'm trying to get ng-bootstrap working using the rather anemic docs on the site.
Let me start off by saying that our team has been using AngularJs 1.x for over a year now on some large projects, but we are new to 2.x / 4.x.  We are also new to WebPack.
I think I have things set up according to the docs, but when i try to add a tabset I get an error.  Here's the details.

First I installed it with

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

And have confirmed that it is in the packages folder.
Here's the different config files.

app.module.browser.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module.shared';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        AppModuleShared
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function getBaseUrl() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}
```

webpack.config.vendor.js

```
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
     . . . . .
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap',
];
```

I have manually reran

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

and confirmed that the vendor.js file is larger and that the contents of the ng-bootstrap library are in that file and being loaded

In a component

```
<ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="Simple">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
             <p>
                Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin
                .........
```

When I run the site I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

NodeInvocationException: Template parse errors:
'ngb-tab' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this 
module.
2. If 'ngb-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
'@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

<ngb-tabset>
[ERROR ->]<ngb-tab title="Simple">
<ng-template ngbTabContent>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Here's the component as requested:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    providers: [NgbTabset],
    selector: 'counter',
    templateUrl: './counter.component.html'
})
export class CounterComponent {
    public currentCount = 0;

    public incrementCounter() {
        this.currentCount = this.currentCount + 3;
    }
}
```

I just added the

```
providers: [NgbTabset],
```

as you suggested and now I'm getting a different error
"NgbTabset is not defined"

Comment: Let us see the component decorator in your components ts file. It seem that your are missing to add  : providers: [NgbTabset]

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that you are not importing `NgbModule` in _all_ modules that you are using it. In which module is the component that uses tabset? Is this module importing `NgbModule`? You need to share more code / details for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource  There is only one module.  This is the default template for a .net core / Angular 4 app, about as simple as it gets as far as I can tell (in terms of not having a bunch of modules).  I've just added the component definition if that helps.

Comment: @DavidL.Sargent you should _not_ be adding `NgbTabset` to providers. What @jetblack is suggesting is plain and simply wrong.

Comment: @DavidL.Sargent I can see 2 modules in your sample code (`AppModule` and `AppModuleShared`) so I'm confused by your code example / statement that there is only one module...

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource  Ahh!  You're a genius!  It was staring me in the face the whole time.  They broke the app into server, browser and shared modules.  I had put it in browser, but it was the server rendering that was blowing up.  When I moved it to shared, which is imported by both, boom, started working.  Nice!  Thank you so much!  If you want to "Answer" the question with that, I'll mark it and give you some rep.